# Thick Line Drawing problem in C#.NET

Tags: c#, graphics, system.drawing

I wanted to draw thick lines using Graphics.Lines() method. But it looks like the API has some bugs. If you try to render the user control with the following code, you would get weird looking image. I was wondering if there is some smoothing mode or something similar that could take care of this line drawing glitch.

```
private void UserControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int n = 100;
        Point[] points = new Point[n];

        double x = 2;
        int y = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Point p = new Point();
            p.X = 200 + (int)(i * x);
            p.Y = 200 + (int)(Math.Sin(i * 0.2) * y);
            points[i] = p;
        }

        Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue));
        //Pen pen = new Pen(new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 100), Color.Black, Color.Red));
        pen.Width = 200;
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points);
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify "weird" with a screenshot?

Comment: Why are you using a width of 200?

Comment: @Michael's on to something: make `pen.Width = 1` and I think you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick reply. I specifically want my application to support different line widths.

Answer (score 6):

You see the effect of GDI+ trying to draw end-caps on the line. That's not going to come to a good end with such a thick pen. About what you'd imagine from daVinci painting the Mona Lisa with a broom.  Fix:

```
        Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue));
        pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square;
        pen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square;
```

Or draw a polygon instead so that GDI+ has a better idea what is front and back:

```
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, points);
```

Well, it doesn't look like a devil anymore.  Keep the line width proportional to the details in the line.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the result of your code drawing using a pen of width 200 (pixels):

[image: 200 pen width]

And here it is at a width of 2:

[image: 2 pen width]

The [pen width property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.width.aspx) is usually pixels, but it is based on the Graphics object's [PageUnit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit.aspx) property (itself a [GraphicsUnit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit.aspx) property). Check to make sure you've set these values to what you want.

Comment: These are the exact results I am getting. GraphicsUnit is set to Pixels. I do not want the first picture to look like a devil. I want it to be smothly drawn.

Comment: If by smoothly you mean without ragged edges, look into AntiAliasing, for example: `g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` (where g is the graphics object). If you are referring to the inverted color spaces (white gaps) where lines overlap, unfortunately that is a separate issue. The thickest line to avoid these gaps is about 105 pixels using your code.

Comment: Hey J, Yes i meant, the filling of the colors in the area of the thick line.